# Notifications don't appear in system tray early after installation

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

If I install my app and fire it up once and then close it and send a notification, nothing happens. If I then open the app, it reacts as though it's been given a notification but it complains that some expected data is missing.

Then, if I open the app and send some notification a few times, eventually notifications appear in the system tray as a square even with the app is closed altogether.

Then eventually, the square turns into the Android icon.

Why does it take time for the system to "warm up" before it works correctly? Does it not know which icon to show unless a notification is received whilst the app is running?

Here is so code...

In OnCreate in MainActivity there's a call at the end to...

```
void HandleNotification()
{
    var intentBundler = Intent.Extras;

    if (intentBundler != null)
    {
        var jobId = intentBundler.GetString("id");

        DroidNotificationStrategy.ReceivedNotification(this, Convert.ToInt32(jobId));
    }
}
```

In the manifest...

```
<application android:label="Connection Crew">
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Firebase services...

```
namespace FCMClient
{
    [Service]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" })]
    public class FirebaseIIDService : FirebaseInstanceIdService
    {
        const string TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

        public static string GetToken() => FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;

        public override void OnTokenRefresh()
        {
            var refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;

            Log.Debug(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

            MessagingCenter.Send<object, (EnumDeviceType, string)>(
                this, "RegisterDevice", (EnumDeviceType.Droid, refreshedToken));
        }

    }

    [Service]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
    public class CCFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
    {
        public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
        {
            var appointmentId = Convert.ToInt32(message.Data["id"]);

            DroidNotificationStrategy.ReceivedNotification(this, appointmentId);
        }
    }
}
```

The message. ("xxBODYxx" is replaced.)

```
@"{
      ""notification"" : {
         ""body"" : ""xxBODYxx"", 
         ""title"" : ""Job"",
         ""icon"": ""ic_notification""
      }, 
       ""data"": {
         ""id"": ""#(JobId)""
      }
}
```

Comment: How did you do it? Add some code.

Comment: @npk I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think launching from a debugger affects notifications appearing in the tray.

If I install using debugger, immediately kill the app and then relaunch and immediately kill the app, the notifications appear fine.